# Google analytics getting value as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in my site for getting searched keyword, source and medium. I got the values for these.  I am using php and js for coding. But my problem is, in some cases keyword, source and medium is showing as undefined. What may be the reason for this?

Comment: you might try here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In October 2011 Google changed their terms to enhance privacy of users.

If a user is logged into a Google account then no referrers are sent (by the analytics script on your site) to *your* Google Analytics account (Google still has that info though) this includes keywords, etc.

Long story short, user privacy => SSL => less juicy analytics data for any of your visitors who are logged into a Google account.

Workarounds: 
[Unlock Keyword Not Provided - by Kissmetrics.com](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/)